# How to disable the custom domains filtering in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

Do you know if there is a way to disable the only verified custom domains usage when new create a new Azure Active Directory user.For example i want to create a user that is using gmail. I have tried to add gmail as custom domain and verify it, but noticed that the steps are related to the dns records of the domain so i cannot do this. I know i can use the invitation service, but i want to directly to create the user without invitation. So did someone experienced this, and if soo i am open for advices.

Have a nice day and stay safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to create a user in Azure Active Directory that is using Gmail. In order to create a user in Azure Active Directory you need to add your domain and verify in Azure Portal.

You need to get your domain name by Go daddy etc... then you need to add in Azure Active directory and verify it. After that you can create a user name under that domain.

I recommend you to go through this [two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain) [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/domains-manage) to get more detailed information.